# Pass a String into an Object type parameter in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working on an Azure DevOps pipeline that is almost entirely based on an existing central template. All  need to do is define parameters and pass these on into the template. Easy, with one complication.

One of these parameters defines the environments to deploy to in the template, as follows:

```
- name: deployEnvironments
  displayName: Environments
  type: object
  default:
  - DEV
  - TST
  - PP
```

If I define my own deployEnvironments parameter the same way, things are straightforward.

**But**... I'd rather not have users deploy to a whole range of environments in one go, and I'd also prefer a dropdown menu over manually inputting environment names. So I would like to set my own pipeline parameter with a dropdown:

```
- name: deployEnvironments
  displayName: Environments
  type: string
  default: DEV
  values:
  - DEV
  - TST
  - PP
```

When I do this and try to pass my deployEnvironments parameter (a string) into the template parameter (an object), I get the error:
*"Expected a sequence or mapping"*

I've unsuccesfully tried to write the string into an array format (same error) and tried a dropdown with type object instead of string (didn't work).

The issue seems to be that ADO pipeline variables are always of type string, and the only way to create an object type, is in a parameter. Suggesting it is not possible to take a string value and turn it into something that the template parameter will accept.

Has anyone ever run into a similar scenario and managed a work-around?

**EDIT:**
In response to Sibtain:

I can't share the entire template, as it comes from a client's repository (and is rather huge), but the parameter in the template is as shown in the first code block.

I refer to it in my own pipelines.yml like this:

```
extends:
  template: utility/yaml/pipeline.modular.yml@templates
  parameters:    
    deployEnvironments: ${{ parameters.deployEnvironments }}
```

Comment: please share the template (where parameter is referred) as well and how it is being passed _to_ the template